# Change pointer cursor in jupyter over ipywidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, traits, ipywidgets

I've been searching and I can't find a way to change the cursor in a jupyter notebook. I'm working with my own designed file chooser using ipywidgets and I want to change the cursor image every time is searching for the folders in a given path, i.e. loading cursor, any thoughts?